# Get isodate from week integer in aggregate query | From 1 get 30/12/2019, from 2 get 06/01/2020

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I have some data that i'd like to plot on charts grouped by week. The dates for the documents are ISODates:

```
"time_initialized" : ISODate("2019-04-02T11:52:55.464Z")
```

I'd like to group all these documents by week, but not as an integer as it doesn't look nice on the x-axis of a chart

I have this aggregation query:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "referralid": 1,
    "time_initialized": 1,
    "week": {
      "$week": "$time_initialized"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$week",
    "chats_opened": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "week": "$_id",
    "chats_opened": 1
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    "week": 1
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
{ "chats_opened" : 8, "week" : 13 }
{ "chats_opened" : 1, "week" : 31 }
{ "chats_opened" : 6, "week" : 32 }
{ "chats_opened" : 2, "week" : 38 }
{ "chats_opened" : 1, "week" : 41 }
```

**What i'd like:**

```
chats_opened: 8, ISODate("2019-03-25T00:00:00.000Z")
```

**Where the date is the first Monday of that week**

Has anyone got a smart and concise way of achieving this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) operator and pass your `week` as a parameter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            week: {
                $dateFromParts: {
                    "isoWeekYear": 2019,
                    "isoWeek": "$week",
                    "isoDayOfWeek": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O9SyhBLO0Rt)